# page renders before the script in $(document).ready is executed to rearrange the html elements

Tags: jquery, dom, load, document-ready

I am re-arranging some html and changing some css values in my `$(document).ready`  in JQuery.  Unfortunately, if the user's computer is not super fast, the user sees the original layout and then sees things being moved around on the screen until the `$(document).ready` completes. I can hide the main `div` and show it at the end of `$(document).ready` but as it happens, depending on the page, I have more than one javascript page loaded for each html page and each of these javascript pages has a $(document).ready function.  So guaranteeing which one executes last is also another hurdle.

To add more complexity, I am getting from the server an html fragment of 100 spans each containing an image. I will only display the first n elements of this html fragment and remove the rest from the dom. n is calculated on the client in javascript.  I want to do this before the images are actually pulled from the server so I pull only the images that are displayed.

How do I write my code so:

1. Only the images that will actually be displayed are pulled from the server. and
2. The user does not see the page elements rearranging in front of them.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1) use `display:none` on your contents as an inline style, and show them after your script is complete

2) Leave the `SRC` blank, and put it into `data_src`, then copy the values to SRC when you're ready to display

```
<img src="" data_src="/images/image1.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks!
1. with multiple $(document).ready functions executing in an order that is not set in stone, how would I know when the script is completed?

2. In this way if the user has javascript disabled, they get no images.

Answer (score 1):

> I have more than one javascript pages loaded for the page and each of these has a $(document).ready function. So guaranteeing which one executes last is also another hurdle.

You can have just one

```
$("document").ready({
 //functions here
});
```

and have all the functions defined inside this.